# Check If VARRAY Type Is Empty

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database table with a column called 'node_names' that is a user defined VARRAY type.  There are records in my database table that have populated the 'node_names' column with an empty VARRAY.

Here is some PL/SQL that attempts to identify empty node names.  It is complaining about the usage of the IS EMPTY clause: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'IS EMPTY'.

```
DECLARE
    x NUMBER := 1;
    CURSOR c1 is select node_names from ahf_definition;
BEGIN
FOR node_names_rec in c1
    LOOP
        IF node_names_rec.node_names IS EMPTY THEN
            INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x, 'empty nodes');
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x, 'nodes');
    END IF;
    x := x + 100;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

How can I write an SQL query that will return all records for which the 'node_names' VARRAY is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IS EMPTY` [applies to nested tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions006.htm#sthref1961). You can use `COUNT` for a `VARRAY`, but only inside your PL/SQL block (as far as I know):

```
DECLARE
    x NUMBER := 1;
    CURSOR c1 is select node_names from ahf_definition;
BEGIN
FOR node_names_rec in c1
    LOOP
        IF node_names_rec.node_names IS NULL
            OR node_names_rec.node_names.count = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x, 'empty nodes');
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x, 'nodes');
    END IF;
    x := x + 100;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I'm also checking for `null` to avoid an error.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee90e/1)

Comment: Thanks.  Looks promising.  I'll give it a go.